# XOR decryption of two plaintext strings

Tags: java, encryption, binary, xor

I was assigned in my AP Java class to decrypt the following:
**umzDlBF8aFix**

with the following key:
**oE2dpffzEiFD**

The only problem is I don't know how to do an XOR to decrypt these. I've gotten as far as turning them into binary:

key: **101000|000100|110110|011101|101001|011111|110011|000100|100010|000101|000011**

ciphertext: **110110|100110|110011|100101|000001|111100|011010|000101|100011|110001**

but I don't know what to do with that. If you could help me with this, that would be great! Code would be nice as well, but not needed.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Think about it: if "encrypt" = plaintext XOR key, then wouldn;t "decrypt" = ciphertext XOR key?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure if the spelling error is a joke but I'm pretty sure that the plaintext is "GiFeMeaPenny" - "Give me a penny".

Comment: "plaintext strings" what are plaintext strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, "xor" is a wonderful encryption mechanism, because the encryption and the decryption are exactly the same operation. If you use every part of the key only once, you have the most secure encryption algorithm possible.

If you re-use any part of the key, it turns into one of the worst encryption mechanisms because that makes it easy to crack.

The problem that you have here is - how do you go from the characters to the value that you want to encrypt.
You could take the Unicode character values but you'd get bogus results with your ciphertext and key. The problem with using Unicode as-is is also that you may get unprintable characters after encryption/decryption, which is normally not a problem, but in textbook examples it is hard to print unprintable characters.

To decrypt your text, I made the assumption that the translation of characters works like this.

- `A` - `Z` => 0 - 25
- `a` - `z` => 26 - 51
- `0` - `9` => 52 - 61

(I didn't need to guess what 62/63 would be but space and point would be good guesses).

Using that assumption and xor, I take your ciphertext `umzDlBF8aFix` and your key `oE2dpffzEiFD` and end up with the plaintext `GiFeMeaPenny`.

Since this is readable English - "**Give me a penny**" - it looks like the assumptions above are plausible.

Answer (score 0):

The XOR operator has the property that T XOR K XOR K == T, so if you want to encrypt a plaintext T with a key K, you apply the operation C = T XOR K, and in order to decrypt the text you just have to apply the same operation again (T = C XOR K). You can apply the XOR operation to every byte in the plaintext using a for loop or a functional programming map.

EDIT : in case you need it, the XOR operator in programming languages is represented by the character "^" so A ^ B means A XOR B.

EDIT2 : simple proof that T XOR K XOR K == T, just so you don't have to accept it like it's magic:

- K XOR K clearly equals 0
- T XOR 0 clearly equals T
- Since XOR operator is associative along with binary numbers, we can write T XOR K XOR K as T XOR (K XOR K) == T XOR 0 == T

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to turn them into binary.  XOR is a bitwise operation, so you can XOR two bytes together, and it will be like XORing each bit of one byte with the corresponding bit of the other byte.

Just write a loop from zero up to (and excluding) the length of the cipher, in which you read each character from the cipher, XOR it with the corresponding character from the key, and append the result to a StringBuilder.  Then invoke `.toString()` on the StringBuilder to get your result.

If your compiler complains that it cannot XOR characters, then cast each `char` to a `byte`, perform the XOR between the bytes, and then cast the result to a `char`.

The `String` class has a `charAt()` method which allows you to get a character from a specific index in the string.  Alternatively, you can begin by obtaining the contents of each string as a char array.  (There is another function for that.)

As a bonus, you can make it so that the key does not have to be of the same length as the cipher.  You can maintain a separate index addressing characters of the cipher, and when this index reaches the length of the cipher you can set it back to zero, thus starting to read the cipher from the beginning.